# I can't access my site: php fatal error from Gutenberg_REST_Global_Styles Controller and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, compatibility, fatal-error, wordpress-gutenberg

The error is PHP Fatal error: Access level to Gutenberg_REST_Global_Styles_Controller_6_2::validate_custom_css() must be protected (as in class WP_REST_Global_Styles_Controller) or weaker in /home/customer/www/my-domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/lib/compat/wordpress-6.2/class-gutenberg-rest-global-styles-controller-6.2.php on line 217

I researched this and found it is due to a gutenberg compatibility issue with the new wordpress core update.  But I haven't found any instructions on how to actually fix it. Can anyone instruct me?

I get a critical error message on trying to open the website and the wp-admin in a browser. I can access the files and know how to make changes there.  But in this case I don't know what to change.   I read through this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59718 but the file is marked "won't fix" and is closed now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable all the plugins from the file manager.  That allowed me into the dashboard.  After updating all the plugins, problem is resolved.